# git clone (SSH) gets reaped by supervisord run in docker

Tags: git, docker, ssh, supervisord

I'm trying to create application for hosting remote git repositories. What I'm trying to do is to allow user clone the repository by SSH, I'm using supervisord to serve my application and sshd, but when I'm trying to clone repository I get:

```
$ git clone git@address:/repositories/some-repo
Cloning into 'some-repo'...
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

and in supervisord log I can see:

```
[date] INFO reaped unknown pid [PID]
```

So in my opinion it's just supervisord who is killing all not known PIDs.
I'm sure that I have set correct access rights to my repositories and my key is added to `authorized_keys` file. My current supervisord config is:

```
[supervisord]
logfile = /tmp/supervisord.log
directory = /tmp
childlogdir = /tmp

[program:app-sshd]
command=/usr/sbin/sshd -D

[program:app-uwsgi]
command = /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --ini /my/path/uwsgi.ini
stopsignal=INT

[program:app-nginx]
command = /usr/sbin/nginx
```

Is there any way to allow git connections in supervisor or will I need to replace my docker container with virtual machine to proceed with this project?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `supervisor` but it looks like a problem with permissions. To clear test - may you disable `supervisor`. Now try to clone your repository. BTW, have you add local ssh-public key to your git server?

Comment: As I said before my key was added in aurhorized_keys file on the server, but when I checked with only ssh daemon in entry point it was acting the same way and I figured out what's wrong with it. User git had shell set to /bin/false and that's why I got logged out just after login.

Comment: From [this github issue](https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/840), the  `INFO reaped unknown pid` message basically just means that supervisord noticed that some other process ended. Somewhat confusingly, it does NOT mean that supervisord killed the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that my user had shell set to `/bin/false` and then he got logged out just after login. Changing it to `/bin/bash` resolved the issue.